# Laravel API middleware: using Auth::onceBasic 2 times (conditions)

Tags: laravel, middleware, basic-authentication

Currently I am creating a middleware for my Laravel project API. The middleware will do HTTP Stateless Basic Authentication. Using `Auth::onceBasic()`, I want to allow authentication using `email` or `workerid`. Since, I can only put 1 parameter only in `Auth::onceBasic()`, here is how I do:

```
    try {
        Auth::onceBasic('staff_id');
    } catch (UnauthorizedHttpException $e) {

        try {
            Auth::onceBasic('email');
        } catch (UnauthorizedHttpException $e) {
            return response()->json(401);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(500);
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        try {
            Auth::onceBasic('email');
        } catch (UnauthorizedHttpException $e) {
            return response()->json(401);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(500);
        }
        
    }
    return $next($request);
```

Luckily, the code is working. However, is there any ways that I can simplify the code?

Answer (score 0):

```php
if (!Auth::onceBasic('staff_id') || !Auth::onceBasic('email')) {
    throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.', 'basic');
}

return $next($request);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?